# Get Started with Foursquare API - Venue Search

Tags: c#, foursquare

I want to integrate Search Venue API in FourSquare into a windows phone app. Any one can point to any get started wiki,blog or docs including samples to how to use it.

I simply want to search for venues by name around me, and those venues which basically as i read on the web site called Venue API.

Any helps is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the SharpSquare SDK that FourSquare recommend for .NET developers: http://www.igloolab.com/sharpsquare/